# Nested Quantifiers - Excluding Self

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I'm trying to understand the following examples of expressing an English sentence using nested quantifiers.

**Example One**
"Everybody loves somebody *else*."
$\forall x \exists y ((x \ne y) \land L(x, y))$

[Relevant table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh04r.png)

I was told that this means that everybody loves at least one other person, but that it does *not exclude* the self: $L(x,x)$.

**Example Two**
"Everybody loves somebody *other than self*."
$\forall x \exists y (L(x, y) \land \neg L(x, x))$

[Relevant table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Abn.png)

Apparently this does exclude the self.

I don't see the difference between these examples. As far as I understand, $(x \ne y)$ is functionally equivalent to $\neg L(x, x)$. Because $(x \ne y)$ is always false at the diagonals, it seems like the first example should also exclude the self.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I do not see however, how either of the natural language sentences conveys that self-love does not exist

Answer (score 1):

The clause "$(x \neq y) \wedge L(x,y)$" explicitly asserts the truth of $x$ loving $y$ for some $y$ that is different from $x$, but is completely silent on the truth of $L(x,x)$.  (The inequality condition ensures that the clause cannot speak to the truth or falsity of $L(x,x)$.)

The clause "$L(x,y) \wedge \neg L(x,x)$" asserts both $L(x,x)$ is false and $L(x,y)$ is true.  This forces $y \neq x$ and also explicitly assigns a truth value to $L(x,x)$.

Comment: So because $(x \ne y)$ always evaluates to false in the case when $L(x, x)$, $(x \ne y)$ always dominates the value of $L(x, x)$? I'm having trouble seeing why it is important to make the distinction that $(x \ne y) \land L(x, y)$ is "completely silent on the truth of" $L(x,x)$, because I can't think of an instance where these examples would have different truth values given the same inputs. Is it a mistake to assume that they're logically equivalent?

Comment: If all you tell me is the value of $L(x,y)$ for $x \neq y$, you never tell me the value of $L(x,x)$.  Since you don't tell me if it is true or false, I can't infer anything about it.